# How can I add columnstore index to existing tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I always use this method, which is "existing table right click script table as > clipboard" when I create a new table in SSMS. Today, I realized this method doesn't create columnstore index.

I realized that this method doesn't add "columnstore index" to script. Shortly, any table doesn't have csi. Therefore I have to add csi to existing tables in SQL Server. What is the fastest way to add csi to existing tables?

Comment: The same way you added it the first time? Is your real question how to *script* an index perhaps? Right click on the index instead of the table

Comment: [`CREATE COLUMNSTORE INDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-columnstore-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ??

Comment: I meant how can i add CSI collectively with script? (do you have script for this problem)

Comment: If you want to script an existing table complete with indexes, use Tasks -> Generate Scripts on the database level and check the appropriate options.